# PHP Mailer Class issue :Message body empty

Tags: php

When i try to send email using PHPMailer class I get this error :
Mailer Error: Message body empty :

```
<?php

    include("class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;

    $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
    $mail->Host       = "rsb20.rhostbh.com";
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->Username   = "jobserreker+furrtexlab.com";
    $mail->Password   = "12345678a";

    $mail->From       = "jobserreker@furrtexlab.com";
    $mail->FromName   = "Job Seeker";
    $mail->Subject    = $_GET['subject'];
    $mail->MsgHTML($_GET['msg']);

    $mail->AddAddress($_GET['to'],"name to");
    $mail->IsHTML(false);

    if(!$mail->Send())
    {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;

    }else{

        echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: any chance $_GET['msg'] is empty?

Comment: If you use $mail->MsgHTML($_GET['msg']); but then say $mail->IsHTML(false); aren't you supposed to use maybe another property to set the text? A property like Body? Or maybe $_GET['msg'] is empty?

Comment: can you please do an `echo '--->' . $_GET['msg'] . '<---', in order to check the content of `$_GET['msg']`?

Comment: How do you access this page in your website? Which URL with which query string? By checking the query string we can tell you more about the emptiness of `$_GET['msg']`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Gerald Versluis said, since you're setting IsHTML() to false, you'll have to use the ->Body property to set the actual body of the mail.

```
$mail->Body = $_GET['msg'];
```

You should also use POST instead of GET for submitting something which causes an action to be performed.

Comment: This is not working also. some messages are sent some of them get that response

Comment: Add a var_dump($mail) when you get the message and post the result in your question. The check that barfs the message simply performs an if (empty($this->Body)), so I'm guessing you're not setting it to the value you think you're setting it to (or calling something else that resets ->Body).

Answer (score 0):

This post has been mentioned in the past here. [Phpmailer sending attachments, but not the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736899/phpmailer-sending-attachments-but-not-the-body)

They found that they could not send the body and the attachments.

Answer (score 0):

I had these two lines of code but didn't have any contents.html file and I had to create one in order to avoid the error.

```
//Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced imagesto embedded,
//convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

//Replace the plain text body with one created manually
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';`
```