# PHPMailer Mailer Error: Message body empty

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm trying to get the basic example working for PHPMailer.

All I done was upload the whole PHPMailer_5.2.2 folder, configured the page below as per the code you see and I keep getting `Mailer Error: Message body empty`, but I can clearly see the contents.html file has html in it and isn't empty. This is the example file I'm using from the PHPMailer PHPMailer_5.2.2/examples/test_smtp_gmail_basic.php

I tried using the settings I have in Outlook for Gmail that works, I know my username and password, the SMTP port is 587 and it's set to TLS, I tried replacing SSL with TLS in the code below, I still get same error.

I also tried the following code, which has been suggested:

changed this:

```
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
```

to this

```
$mail->body = $body;
```

I still got same error, is there something else I need to configure? It's my first time using PHPMailer, I can get the standard php mail working, but I want to try this because the page I'm going to be emailing has lots of html and I don't want to have to go through all the html and enter character escapes so someone recommending using this.

```
<?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(E_STRICT);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "xxx@gmail.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "xxx";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('xxx@gmail.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("xxx","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "xxx.net";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you paste the result of a `var_dump` on the `body` variable? $mail = new PHPMailer(); $body = file_get_contents('contents.html'); $body = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body); var_dump($body); $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

Comment: It just comes up as null when i run that code, i also tried putting the full url www.mysite.com/PHPMailer_5.2.2/examples/contents.html

When i access that URL i can see the html

Comment: I tried $body = "this is a test" first time around it refused it, i got an email from google saying it was suspicious and blocked so i went trough some verification steps and now i can send it if the body is plain text, but once i put back:

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body);

I still get the empty message and running your code i get NULL

The other thing is even though it sent the plain text message i didnt recieve the email

Comment: Can you post a screenshot/overview of your folder structure?

Comment: Strange, when i removed this line it works fine? $body             = preg_replace('/[\]/','',$body); is that needed for anything?

Comment: Not really, since you have control over the HTML code you're sending, no replacing should happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Mailer Class issue :Message body empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506691/php-mailer-class-issue-message-body-empty)

Comment: @Manuel Hi did you get the correct answer? I'm also facing the same issue. please help me to solve this Thanks in advance

Comment: @developer if I rememeber correctly (it was 7 year ago), I ditched PHP Mailer for SwiftMailer, these days I'm using Symfony Mailer both standalone and with Symfony Framework

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem and I solved just changing:

This:

```
$mail->body = 'Hello, this is my message.';
```

Into this:

```
$mail->Body = 'Hello, this is my message.';
```

`body` into `Body` what a little mistake!

Comment: Damn, thats hurting my eyes. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

PHPMailer->MsgHTML() tries to do something clever with fixing non-absolute URLs, but for me too it just returns empty.

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Body=$body;
```

Answer (score 0):

First I had to enable the ssl extension, (which I have obtained from another post on this site). To do that, open php.ini and enable php_openssl.dll by changing

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Now, enable tls and use port 587. Then comment out the `preg_replace`.

Finally, I was able to make it show up in my gmail "Sent" file, although I was expecting to see it in my "Inbox".

This site is awesome! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When setting `$mail->Body` equal to variable the body is empty.
When I attach a string to the body everything works fine.
The solution is to `strval()` a variable containing Your HTML code.

```
$message;//Your HTML message code
$mail->Body = strval($message);
```