# Getting "Mailer Error: Message body empty" when triggering with cronjob

Tags: php, email, cron, phpmailer

I'm trying to send automatic emails every week with a cronjob.
However, I get the error message "Mailer Error: Message body empty".

For the email, I use a .html template.

When I trigger the .php script by calling its URL it works perfectly.
But when it's triggered by the cronjob it gives me that message.

The host I use is hostinger and I'm using their internal cronjob system.

This is my .php script.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$msg = file_get_contents('./contact.html'); 

$msg = str_replace('$message', $message, $msg);

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'myusername';
$mail->Password = 'mypassword';
$mail->setFrom('frommail@mail.com', 'frommail');
$mail->addReplyTo('mail@mail.com', 'mail');
$mail->addAddress($username I get from the database, $username I get from the database);
$mail->Subject = 'subject';
$mail->MsgHTML($msg);
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    $response = ["Result" => "error"];
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response = ["Result" => "success"];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Comment: Does this post solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816571/phpmailer-mailer-error-message-body-empty

Comment: That issue is for when your phpmailer isn't working at all. my phpmailer works when calling the URL directly. But gives an error when triggered by a cronjob.

Comment: can you check , when you are using cron , it gets the contact.html content in the $msg variable, i think it's not getting the contents

Comment: Maybe there is file permision or path issue issue so before set cron just echo your msg veriable and verify its fetch file contents or not.

Comment: @NielsHensen if you are using linux or ubutu server then its matter what is your file group (or owner) its ec2 or ubutu user or root and your cron are execute with root user or oher user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very likely that your cron job is run by a different user than when run via your web server, and that user may not have ownership or sufficient permissions to read the `contact.html` file. If `msgHTML()` fails, it will return an empty string, so you could check that before you try to send (though I notice you have omitted the `send()` call from the script in your question, and you don't show any error handling either).

Comment: I contacted my host and they checked. The permissions are set correctly

Comment: Don’t believe them. Check. What happened when you checked the return value from `msgHTML()`? What do your error logs say?